# prove or disprove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^2+2n- \sin nx}$ converge uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: uniform-convergence

I need to prove or disprove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^2+2n- \sin nx}$$ converge uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$. First I tried using Weierstrass theorem to prove that the series converge uniformly, but I couldn't find a suitable series, so I moved to try to both prove and disprove uniform convergence using Cauchy criterion, but I'm was unable to neither prove that the criterion is fulfilled for every $\varepsilon > 0$ nor find an $\varepsilon$ that disprove it

Comment: Use `\sin` to get a nicely formatted "sin" function, instead of it rendering as the three variables $s$ times $i$ times $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirestrass's test is too weak here, as your series doesn't converge absolutely.

First, lets get rid of $\sin$: say
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{x^2 + 2n - \sin nx} =\\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (-\sin nx)}{2n(x^2+2n-\sin nx)} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^2 + 2n} =\\
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (-\sin nx)}{2n(x^2+2n-\sin nx)} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^2}{2n(x^2 + 2n)}
$$.

The first series converges uniformly by Weierstrass's test (for $n > 2$ common term is bounded by $\frac{1}{n^2}$).

The second converge uniformly as it converges and doesn't depend on $x$ at all

The third converges uniformly by [Abel's test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsUniformConvergenceTest.html), take $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ and $f_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + 2n}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second line $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n(x^2+2n-\sin nx)} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^2+2n}$ wouldn't it be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n(x^2+2n-\sin nx)} - \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^2+2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x^2+2n - 2nx^2 - 4n + 2n\sin nx)}{2n(x^2+2n-\sin nx)(x^2+2n)}$?

Comment: True, I have lost $\sin nx$ in numerator (and also mixed signs). The main idea is that $\frac{1}{a + b} = \frac{1}{a} - \frac{b}{a(a + b)}$, so if $a_n$ grows fast enough and $b_n$ is bounded, convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{a_n + b_n}$ is the same as convergence of $\frac{1}{a_n}$.